# Updating dependent package Microsoft.Data.SqlClient

Tags: nuget

There is a vulnerability in Microsoft.Data.SqlClient and the nuget package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer uses a vulnerable version of this package.

Even the newest version uses Microsoft.Data.SqlClient 5.1.1 which is vulnerable.

How do I go about updating Microsoft.Data.SqlClient to a secure version?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, I installed the newest version of Microsoft.Data.SqlClient through nuget and it seems that the framework picks that up an uses that.